# play Sony DVF File with java API

Tags: java, audio

I am working on project with which requires to read differant audio files. But I am failed to play Sony DVF Extention. I have tried ["Java Sound API"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html)

Howerver its does not work with DVF Files. Requir help on how to play dvf files using java.